# How to join multiple images into one preview

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics, vector-graphics, image-processing

I have hundreds of vector clip art sets (EPS and AI) with JPEG previews for each vector image and I need to create nice preview image for each set (preview image must contain all jpeg previews of one set). How can I batch the process? Or create some kind of template, where I can just grab-and-drop images to create for example one image from five (one big image and 4 small images under it)?

I can show you the example of this king of preview images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm 100% sure that there is some kind of software where I can create the template and just upload the images to that template.

Comment: i think that is a manual process, but i am not sure. You can use the bridge if you want

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing I can recommend is an Adobe Extension called [Tych Panel](http://lumens.se/tychpanel/)

> Tych Panel is an extension to Adobe Photoshop that automates diptychs and triptychs creation. It supports an arbitrary number of layouts using the compositing feature making it the perfect tool for your photo blog